# Exit quietly (without exception) haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, exit

I know that

```
exitWith ExitSuccess
```

exits the program, but it outputs

```
*** Exception: ExitSuccess
```

I am wanting to know if there is way to exit **without** outputting anything onto the screen?

Comment: It shouldn't print that, what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Are you executing that code in ghci? When I *compile* the code it doesn't print that, but using ghci it does show the error.  I believe it's because ghci adds a custom exception handler (in fact it doesn't exit at all!)

Comment: I am using Haskell Platform, which I believe executes in ghci. Here is a snippet of my code: if opt == 3 then do exitWith ExitSuccess else ...

Comment: @Ali The Haskell Platform is a platform that contains GHC (which includes GHCi) and Cabal and many other useful libraries. So that information doesn't really tell us wether you are using GHC or GHCi.

Comment: I run the program in ghci

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding the above comments here (Credits to Reid, Bakuriu and Jeffrey). It's highly likely that you are executing the following program in `ghci`:

```
import System.Exit

main :: IO ()
main = exitWith ExitSuccess
```

Now in terminal:

```
$ ghci
λ> :load crash.hs -- crash.hs is the filename
λ> main
*** Exception: ExitSuccess
```

Note that `ghci` and `ghc` are different. `ghci` is used as a REPL for Haskell. The above code when compiled and executed like the following won't produce any message:

```
$ ghc -o crash crash.hs 
$ ./crash
```

Note that the REPL is invoked through the program named `ghci`. For compiling and producing an executable, you have to use a executable named `ghc`.

Comment: So should I just ignore the the "*** Exception: ExitSuccess" output that ghci produces and continue with the code?

Comment: @Ali Yes, you can ignore it in `ghci`. It doesn't matter anyway. All you have to worry is the exit status of the process. And that is `0` as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I have accepted your answer, which is an addition of the three comments before.